# Check the status of ownership data using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'd like to ask for advice.
So, I'm building a Node.js and MongoDB application for Apartment ownership. And in the application, there are two data: Ownership and Tenants.
For example, Mr. A has units 10 and 11. Then there is Mr. C renting unit 11 owned by Mr. A. How do you show the status of unit 10 belonging to Mr. A and the status of unit 11 being rented to Mr. C?

Here's my controller.js code:

```
const Ownership = require("./owner/model").Ownership;
const Lease = require("./tenant/model").Tenant;
const Tenant = require("../customer/model").Customer;

const errorHandler = require("../controllers/errorController");

exports.listContract = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    // let data = [];
    const dataOwnership = await Ownership.find().populate("unit", "-__v");
    let dataLease = await Lease.find().populate("unit", "-__v");

    dataOwnership.forEach((el, index) => {
      if (el.unit.cdunt !== dataLease[index].unit.cdunt) {
        dataLease.push(el);
      }
    });

    res.status(200).json({
      status: "success",
      data: dataLease,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return errorHandler(err);
  }
};

exports.listUnitByTenant = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const dataUser = await User.findById(req.params.id);
    const dataTenant = await Tenant.findOne({ _id: dataUser.tenant });
    let dataUnit = await Ownership.find({ cstmr: dataTenant._id })
      .populate("cstmr", "-__v")
      .populate({
        path: "unit",
        model: "Unit",
        select: "-__v",
        populate: [
          {
            path: "flr",
            model: "Floor",
            select: "-__v",
            populate: {
              path: "blk",
              model: "Block",
              select: "-__v",
              populate: {
                path: "grpid",
                model: "BlockGroup",
                select: "-__v",
              },
            },
          },
          {
            path: "unttp",
            model: "UnitType",
            select: "-__v",
          },
          {
            path: "untrt",
            model: "UnitRate",
            select: "-__v",
          },
        ],
      });

    if (dataUnit.length === 0) {
      dataUnit = await Lease.find({ cstmr: dataTenant._id })
        .populate("cstmr", "-__v")
        .populate({
          path: "unit",
          model: "Unit",
          select: "-__v",
          populate: [
            {
              path: "flr",
              model: "Floor",
              select: "-__v",
              populate: {
                path: "blk",
                model: "Block",
                select: "-__v",
                populate: {
                  path: "grpid",
                  model: "BlockGroup",
                  select: "-__v",
                },
              },
            },
            {
              path: "unttp",
              model: "UnitType",
              select: "-__v",
            },
            {
              path: "untrt",
              model: "UnitRate",
              select: "-__v",
            },
          ],
        });
    }
    res.status(200).json({
      status: "success",
      data: dataUnit,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).json({
      status: "error",
      message: "Something Went Wrong",
    });
  }
};
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For this I will probably make one unit model with properties owners and tenants which both are array of references for type user , and in the ownership controller I will check the tenant first and if the data is present return that as current owner and if not return the original owner as current owner

Comment: Hi @sidhant, thanks for reply. But sorry, can you elaborate this? I mean about the code

Comment: oh ya, I already make model for the owners and tenants

Comment: He means that instead of Ownership, Tenant and Customer, delete the models Ownership and Tenant and rename Customer to User. Then create a model Apartment/Unit which has two properties: owner and tenant. An Apartment.owner is a User. Apartment.tenant is also a User, maybe Apartment.tenant can be an array of User in case you can split rental of an apartment

Comment: hi @slebetman, do you mean i have to combine Ownership model and Tenant model?

Comment: Yes. The key to understand sidhant's suggestion is to realise that Ownership and Tenant are not models, they are properties of units. There are only two models in your system - Units and People (which I called User). For example: `Mark = new User()` and `Bob = new User()`. Then `apartment = new Unit()`. Let `apartment.owner = Mark` and `apartment.tenant = Bob`

Comment: Looking for an apartment rented by Bob would be `Unit.findByTenant(Bob)`

Comment: Alright, I understand. But, can I automatically display whether the unit has tenants or not? because when there are tenants, the invoice will be sent to the tenant. And, when there are no tenants the invoice is sent to the owner